# How to Relsove the derivative for '_cudnn_rnn_backward' is not implemented for WGAN-LSTM with gradient penalty

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I try to train an WGAN with LSTMs as critic and generator for immage generation on the MNIST dataset.
Unfortunately I keep on running into the error message:

```
NotImplementedError: the derivative for '_cudnn_rnn_backward' is not implemented. Double backwards is not supported for CuDNN RNNs due to limitations in the CuDNN API. To run double backwards, please disable the CuDNN backend temporarily while running the forward pass of your RNN. For example: 
with torch.backends.cudnn.flags(enabled=False):
   output = model(inputs)
```

I have trouble to understand this error message, since don't think I perform `Double backwards` operations.
Could you help me understand where this error message comes from, and how to resolve it?

Here are the relevant parts of my Implementation:

Critic

```
class LSTM_Critic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(LSTM_Critic, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(IMG_SIZE, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x, labels):
        # Set initial hidden and cell states 
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).requires_grad_().to(device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).requires_grad_().to(device)

        # Passing in the input and hidden state into the model and  obtaining outputs
        x = x.reshape(BATCH_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)
        out, hidden = self.lstm(x, (h0.detach(), c0.detach()))  # out: tensor of shape (batch_size, seq_length, hidden_size)
        #Reshaping the outputs such that it can be fit into the fully connected layer
        
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out
```

Initialisation

```
gen = LSTM_Generator(200, 100, num_layers, num_classes).to(device)
critic = LSTM_Critic(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes).to(device)

initialize_weights(gen)
initialize_weights(critic)

# initializate optimizer
opt_gen = optim.Adam(gen.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE, betas=(0.0, 0.9))
opt_critic = optim.Adam(critic.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE, betas=(0.0, 0.9))

gen.train()
critic.train()
```

Training

```
for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    for batch_idx, (real, labels) in enumerate(tqdm(loader)):
        real = real.to(device)
        cur_batch_size = real.shape[0]
        labels = labels.to(device)

        # Train Critic: max E[critic(real)] - E[critic(fake)]
        # equivalent to minimizing the negative of that
        for _ in range(CRITIC_ITERATIONS):
            noise = torch.randn(cur_batch_size, Z_DIM, 1, 1).to(device)
            fake = gen(noise, labels)
            critic_real = critic(real, labels).reshape(-1)
            critic_fake = critic(fake, labels).reshape(-1)

            gp = gradient_penalty(critic, labels, real, fake, device=device)
            loss_critic = (
                -(torch.mean(critic_real) - torch.mean(critic_fake)) + LAMBDA_GP * gp
            )
            critic.zero_grad()
            loss_critic.backward(retain_graph=True)
            opt_critic.step()
```

Gradient Penalty

```
def gradient_penalty(critic, labels, real, fake, device="cpu"):
    BATCH_SIZE, C, H, W = real.shape
    alpha = torch.rand((BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, 1)).repeat(1, C, H, W).to(device)
    interpolated_images = real * alpha + fake * (1 - alpha)

    # Calculate critic scores
    mixed_scores = critic(interpolated_images, labels)

    # Take the gradient of the scores with respect to the images
    gradient = torch.autograd.grad(
        inputs=interpolated_images,
        outputs=mixed_scores,
        grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(mixed_scores),
        create_graph=True,
        retain_graph=True,
    )[0]



    gradient = gradient.reshape(gradient.shape[0], -1)
    gradient_norm = gradient.norm(2, dim=1)
    gradient_penalty = torch.mean((gradient_norm - 1) ** 2)
    return gradient_penalty
```

The code fails at the line `loss_critic.backward(retain_graph=True)`

Comment: You might find some ideas [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/wgan-gradient-penalty-error-even-with-retain-graph-true/113266/3)